# Calling member function from within a standalone function

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error "reference to non-static member function must be called", however if I call it the way my book says:

```
Mammal myMammal;
myMammal.mammals[i].printExhibitForAnimals
```

it says "no member named 'mammals' in Mammal"

```
void printExhibit(Mammal mammals[], Personnel personnel[],
string exhibitToFind, int numMammals, int numPersonnel)
{
    int combo = numMammals + numPersonnel;

    for (int i = 0; i < combo; i++){
        mammals[i].printExhibitForMammals;
        personnel[i].printExhibitForPersonnel;
    } 
}
```

Relevant section of header file:

```
struct Mammal {
    std::string species;
    Date birthDate;
    int weight;
    SizeOfEnclosure sizeofenclosure;
    std::string exhibitName;
    Mammal();

    void getMammalsData(std::ifstream& inFile);
    void displayMammals(Mammal mammals[], int totalMammals);
    void printExhibitForMammals(Mammal mammals[],std::string     
exhibitNameToFind, int numMammals);
};
```

Comment: You ought to post the code (or the relevant section in) the `Mammal` header file.

Comment: There is no mammals member in the Mammal structure.

Comment: @Marker mammals is an array that is being read from a member function in the structure

Comment: @Hannah: But there is no `mammals` field in the `Mammal` struct. So this fails: `myMammal.mammals[i].printExhibitForAnimals`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues here.

1. The Mammal structure does not have a mammals array. So you could not call something like Mymammal.mammals[i].
2. In printExhibit function when you invoke printExhibitForMammals function, it should be called with parameters. That would explain the error message saying that "non-static member function must be called"